# Add custom button while pop up in struts2 - jquery grid plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, struts2-jquery

how to add a custom button when the user clicks a button and a pop up pops up.in that pop up i want to add a custom button. Struts2 jquery grid is the name of the plugin i am using.And i want to ad this custom button in the same plugin.
thanks in advance  :)

Comment: This is REALLY not clear... post some code, add some information, or i doubt anyone could help you...

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the dialog plugin, you can pop it up by publishing the topic which it is listening to.

```
<sj:dialog 
            id="itemDialog" 
            openTopics="openDialog" 
            closeTopics="closeDialog"
            autoOpen="false"
            modal="true" 
            resizable="false"
            position="['center',150]"
            title="My Dialog"
            buttons="{
                    'OK':function() { dosomething();$.publish('closeDialog'); },
                    'Cancel':function() { $.publish('closeDialog'); }
                    }"      

        >
            Please confirm

        </sj:dialog>
```

In this example, publish `openDialog` so the dialog would pop up.